# how can I add a json as an attribute value in an element?

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3.js v5. I want to know promptly if it is possible to add a `json` inside an `element` like a `rect`. For example I want to add this `json`:

```
var data = {"name": "pedro"}
```

in some property of my element to then get that json.

I currently do it as follows, but it remains as a string, I would like to know what is the best way to save it directly like a json.

```
        var rect=d3.select("svg").append("rect");
        rect.attr("myjson", function () {
            return JSON.stringify(data) //I save it this way to avoid the [object, object]
        })
```

later

```
        console.log(rect.attr("myjson)) // output is a string
```

how can do it?

**Note:**

I know this question seems weird, but I want to know if it is occasionally possible to do this, and I could convert the string to a `json` (`rect.attr("myjson)`), but I want to know if I can avoid this step by saving it as a `json` directly.

Comment: Why not bind the data with `.append("rect").datum(myjson)` - you can access it with `rect.datum()` - why save it as an attribute?

Comment: @AndrewReid exact! I didn't know there was something like that. Thank you very much, post your answer to rate it and help other users. Can you help me with this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036844/is-there-a-way-to-add-multiple-properties-in-an-attr-instead-of-doing-attrk